# Visual Studio add-in/extension for adding/removing/handling references easily

Tags: visual-studio, reference, add-in, visual-studio-addins

I'm looking for a way of handling references in an easier way in Visual Studio.

Is there an extension that provides one of those features:

- Copy references from a project to another
- Drag & Drop `.dll` files from Windows Explorer to the *References* folder in the Visual Studio solution?
- Edit the *Path* of those dlls that aren't found in the Solution?
- Any other interesting feature...

**Edit:**
It would be great to have all those features in a single place, but I'm just looking for an extension that provides any of the first 3.

Comment: If you are voting for closing this question, could you at least provide a reason here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "Copy references from a project to another", you can use the Copy Reference and Paste Reference commands of [Visual Studio Powertoys](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3f0c30-3d37-4e06-9ef8-3bff3508be31).

Visual Studio 2010's [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef?SRC=Featured) offers a better, quicker Add Ref dialog.